# Как сравнить элемент массива с элементами заданного массива?

Tags: c++

У меня есть массив из символов: `char cif[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', ',','.', '/', ';'};`

Также есть строка `string s = "abcd123";`

Мне нужно узнать есть ли в строке s элементы из массива cif

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            if (s[i] == cif)
            {
               /.........../
            }
        }
```

Comment: string s = "abcd123";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

строка в c++  - это массив символов типа char.

```
char cif[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', ',','.', '/',';'};
char s[]="abcd123";
for (int i=0, i<14, i++) {
    for (int j=0, j<7, j++) {
        if (s[j]==ciff[i]) {
            cout << "Yes " << s[j] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Тебе нужно два цикла, первый - идет по массиву символов, второй - по массиву строки, в зависимости от того какая у тебя строка - вместо 7 ставь либо n (если строка из n символов) или другое число, если оно заранее известно.

Comment: Неверный был у вас вывод в stdout и форматирование

Comment: `cout<<"Yes, "s[j]; endl;`???

Comment: промахнулся с запятой, 
cout<<"Yes", s[ j ]; <<endl;

Answer (score 3):

Если ваш `s` - это `std::string`, то ответ на вопрос дается простым

```
bool yes = s.find_first_of(cif, 0, sizeof cif) != s.npos;
```

А если вы оформите ваш `cif` в виде нуль-терминированной строки

```
char cif[] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',',','.','/',';','\0'};
// или просто
char cif[] = "0123456789,./;";
// или 
const char *cif = "0123456789,./;";
```

то можно будет записать и чуть короче

```
bool yes = s.find_first_of(cif) != s.npos;
```

Comment: s.end() это итератор, а метод возвращает  size_t  со значением  std::string::npos при неудачи

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Да, верно. Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t pos = s.find_first_of("0123456789,./;");
if (pos != s.npos)
    cout << "найден символ " << s[pos] << '\n';
```